# DC++ or ADC on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, dc++

I already found some clients, like EiskaltDC++ and Shakespeer, that seem to work.
I was wondering if hub/server software for Mac OS X exists. Any recommendations?

Comment: For DC hubs, see this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_Connect_%28protocol%29#Operating_system_support

Comment: For ADC hubs, see this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_ADC_software#Operating_system_support

Answer (score 0):

**ADC**

- uHub
- DSHub (Java, discontinued)
- Erlhub
- Starhub

ADC+NMDC

- Flexhub - TBT! (LUA, must work on any platform)